# Is there any open source cloud messaging system like NATS?

Tags: cloud-service

I saw NATS messaging system for cloud and it is open source but codes are writing with Go language( Server written in Go. ). Is there any open source cloud messaging system that uses Python or Java (both server and client) ? Thanks.